Floating-point operation
I am trying to prove that fl($fl(x)^m$)=x$(1+ε)^{2m-1}$ for a $|ε|<=u $. I used fl(x)=x(1+ε) for $|ε|<=u $ and the intermediate value theory  for: $\prod_{i=1}^{m} ({1+ε_{i}})$ =$(1+ε)^m$ with $ε_i$ being the errors that occured in the multiplications of fl(x) in each step and  $|ε_i|<=u$ but i concluded that fl($fl(x)^m$)=$x^m$ $(1+ε)^{2m}$. What am I doing wrong?

The target expression is valid, but without additional details it is impossible to say where the mistake occurred.

u is the unit rounding error x is a real number and m a natural number.

why is the target valid? shouldn't be x^m rather than just x?

The real issue is the difference between $2m-1$ and $2m$, right?

actually i tried it again and i find 2m-1 as well. my problem is the power of x

Without a doubt it should be $x^m$ and not $x$.
